# Server with static IP is not showing up in Computer Browser?

Tags: windows, netbios

We have two servers on a Windows network.  One is both the primary domain controller, as well as the DHCP and DNS server.  The other one is just a file and database server.  Both machines use static IPs.  From any of the workstations, if I go to My Computer > Network, then it lists all of the machines *except* for the file/network server.  I can use `nslookup` and that returns the right IP address.  I can `ping` it.  The computer browsing service is running on both servers.

The primary domain controller is also the WINS server and it has a static mapping for the file server.  It is the master browser.  There is a static DNS mapping for the file server.  I can even use a UNC path to get to a fileserver share: `\\myfileserver\share`, and mapped network drives work fine.

Both servers have "Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP" checked in the network settings.

Why can't I see the server in the "network neighborhood"?

**Edit**:

When I go to browse the windows network from the file server itself, I can see the domain listed, but under the domain, there are no computers.

Comment: Because network browsing has always been notoriously unreliable. Prior to Windows Vista all that was needed was for NetBIOS over TCP to be enabled, File and Printer sharing to be bound to the NIC and for the Server service to be running and for Shares to exist. Now there's all of that plus LLMNR, Network Discovery, etc., etc. What problem is this causing? You can access the server by ip address and UNC path. Why is it important to see it while browsing the network?

Comment: What OS is running on the server? If Windows 2008 or later do you have `Network Discovery` enabled?

Comment: @joeqwerty - this is a Small Business Server 2003. There is a network scanner that writes scanned documents to a user's file share, and it doesn't seem to be able to write to the shares now.  At the same time this happened, people complained that they couldn't find the server when they went to browse the network (if it was only the latter problem, I'd not worry about it).  I just think it's related.  The trigger for all this is that we changed IP addresses (192.168 subnet to 10.0 subnet).  However we think we've found every place where the IPs are changed.

Answer (score 1):

Both servers used Teamed network cards, and on the one that wasn't working, it had "Network Load Balancing" checked on the TEAM network adapter.  When I turned that off, the scanner could see the shares, and the server could see all the other computers in the computer browser.